# Python-based method for finding an object by name

Tags: python, object, types, widget, self

I'd like some advice on how to better extract objects from the 'self' construct by name such that the object is returned for the string of its type is provided.

My working code is presented below.

```
def makeObjectTypeList(self):
    objectList      = []
    allObjects      = dir( self )

    for att in allObjects:
        test                = getattr(self, att)
        test1               = test.__class__.__name__
        test2               = len( re.split( self.objectType, test1) )
        if test2 > 1:
            objectList.append( att)
    self.objectList         = objectList
```

The value for self.objectType is the string 'QDial'.  And, I return all instances of objects of QDial from the method with the re.split() method and the check on the number of items in its result (e.g., len(re.split()) > 1).

My question is how to make this more compact using 'enumerate', etc. in the mode of Python coding.  My code is general so that I can pass it 'QLablel', 'QTabWidget', etc. in self.objectType, and obtain all such type-matched instances.  But, it feels clunky, and I don't bother yet to trap for the case of a non-existent class type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension that iterates through the attribute-value pairs of the dict returned by the `vars` function and retain only those whose class of the value matches `self.objectType`:

```
def makeObjectTypeList(self):
    self.objectList = [k for k, v in vars(self).items() if v.__class__.__name__ == self.objectType]
```